# Javac não compila .java

Tags: java

O erro de retorno é esse, quando já estou na pasta aparece essa informação:

```
--javac Main.java

'--javac' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Tentei sem traços e até com um traço. Estou utilizando `Intellij Idea` como IDE.

Comment: Você tem a variável JAVA_HOME setada no ambiente? Está executando os comandos no diretório do Java(Java\"versão da jdk"\bin)? E você está utilizando os comandos pelo cmd?

Comment: Sim, o problema foi que não compilou, dai estou tentando o run do eclipse e deu certo. eu instalei o java 8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Após instalar o [**JDK**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt) (Java Development Kit), abra as propriedades do seu computador,
([image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] + <kbd>Pause Break</kbd>  ou  *Iniciar* → *Painel de Controle* → *Sistema*) e clique em *Configurações Avançadas do Sistema*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em *Variáveis de Ambiente...*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em *Novo* e crie as duas variáveis a seguir:

```
CLASSPATH = .;%JAVA_HOME%
JAVAHOME = Caminho do Java instalado
```

Após criar as variáveis, edite a variável `Path` e coloque um ponto-e-vírgula (`;`) no final do valor e acrescente o caminho da pasta `bin` onde o Java foi instalado anteriormente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após configurado estes passos, reinicie o computador para aplicar as configurações e podes compilar seu código `.java` simplesmente digitando `javac` e o nome do arquivo `.java` no *prompt* do Windows. E executando informando `java` seguido da classe compilada anteriormente.

Para deixar documentado a resposta...

Comment: Bem vindo e boa resposta, Renato, +1

Comment: Mamão com açúcar. Parabéns, muito bem detalhado.

Comment: Boa sua dica... vou tentar ela. Está bem explicada e resumida.

Comment: @Renato Editei a tua resposta pois algumas imagens estavam "quebradas".

Answer (score 2):

Você faz a configuração do path do compilador? [solução possível](http://programareviver.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/configurando-compilador-java-windows.html)
Esta IDE que você está usando pode não compilar direto, reconhecendo o path do compilador; você conferiu esse detalhe?

Tentou compilar pelo prompt direto?

Comment: Sim. o comando não foi aceito no prompt, vou tentar com o eclipse.

Comment: Cara, simplesmente um luxo... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnORjqZUMIQ&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBq0KXHsp5J3PxyFaBIXVs3r

Comment: dei uma olhada no seu link me parece otimo. Obrigado

Comment: Eu utilizei o o eclipse e rodou tranquilo com o run...

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que for acessar um sistema para programar em Java, execute java -version para saber se o Java está instalado.

Se já estiver instalado, este problema ocorre por causa de variáveis de ambiente não setadas.
O sistema operacional usa o PATH para salvar caminhos que podem ser acessados globalmente dentro do sistema operacional, sem especificar o caminho total, apenas o nome do arquivo em uma pasta.

Como o javac está na basta PROGRAM FILES/JAVA 1.6/bin, você precisa criar essa entrada nas variáveis de ambiente, permitindo assim acesso global ao conteúdo desta pasta.

Comment: Sugiro você dar uma lida em **http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help** e também em **[answer]**

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema!

Após instalar o JDK, no prompt consultei **java -version** e rodou normalmente. Porém o **javac -version** não compilou e apresentou a mensagem **'javac' não é reconhecido como um interno ou externo...**, mesmo com todas as variáveis de ambiente devidamente configuradas.

***A solução:***: verifiquei que a versão java -version era diferente da que havia acabado de instalar, haviam duas versões instaladas na máquina que estava preparando. Desinstalei a versão anterior, entrei novamente no prompt e compilou de boa.