# tento executar o comando javac mais não executa

Tags: java

eu ja tentei de toda , forma concertar , ja fui no google , youtube , quando vou tentar executar o cmd "javac" ele nao executa fala o seguinte erro " javac " nao é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo um programa operável ou um a arquivo em lotes. me ajuda por favor

Comment: A pergutna vai ser eventualmente excluída, pois não encaixa no formato do nosso site (veja a seção de ajuda). Porém, vou deixar uma dica aqui: verifique se você tem o Java instalado na máquina e configurado no seu PATH. O que o prompt está lhe dizendo é que esse executável que você está tentando usar NON ECZISTE na tua máquina.

Comment: P.s.: da próxima vez que escrever `mais` quando queres dizer "mas" eu não ajudo ;)

Comment: Veja se a resposta dessa pergunta ajuda em algo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31465/6454

Comment: Só para deixar claro, eu e o @stderr votamos como duplicata de "http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31465/6454" - Ocorre que o sistema do SO dá como razão de fechamento apenas o voto da maioria (os demais três votantes).

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu votei antes da duplicata aparecer, senão teria votado duplicata também, infelizmente o sistema também não me permite troca de voto.

Answer (score 1):

A sua JDK não foi instalada corretamente. Você pode baixar o instalador [aqui](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt).

Comment: Não pode ser só a variável de ambiente faltando? Isto é, se o AP usa Windows.