# javac -classpath . (Debian 10 Buster)

Tags: java, linux, geany

Estou usando o **Geany** para tal. Porém, não estava conseguindo compilar o simples **Hello World!**. Com algumas pesquisas eu encontrei dois links de referência, sendo eles:

https://www.guj.com.br/t/ola-mundo/51431/13

[Javac não compila .java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31465/javac-n%c3%a3o-compila-java)
.

Com o primeiro link, eu consegui encontrar a solução para o erro de compilação, adicionando do **-classpath .** entre o **javac** e **HelloWorld.java**. Porém, pesquisando sobre isso, me esbarrei no segundo link, porém, estou usando o **Debian 10**, e não consegui ligar muito bem os pontos. Se não for incômodo, posso esclarecer a minha (talvez) boba dúvida, aqui?

Veja no console do Geany:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro apresentado:

```
philip@debian:~/Documents/java/java1$ javac Mundo.java 

Mundo.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.printfln("Hello World!");
                  ^
  symbol:   method printfln(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

Já na aba do **compiler**, ele mostra esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que usei o comando **javac -classpath . Mundo.java**, na pasta atual do meu arquivo **.java** ele começa a compilar normalmente, como se nunca houvesse erro. Sempre que eu for compilar um arquivo **.java**, devo fazer este procedimento ou é alguma má configuração?

Comment: E qual erro ocorre? E porque está usando o `--classpath` se é apenas um simples helloworld?. É importante **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva aonde falhou. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura.  Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Comment: Pronto Guilerme. Adicionei novas informações, espero que esteja claro agora.

Comment: Olá Philip. [Não use imagens para mostrar códigos e logs como imagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Só pra constar, **Não existe `System.out.printfln`** se não vai passar valores com os parâmetros. É erro de digitação no seu código. Só pra constar, não tem necessidade de especificar o -classpath se você não vai apontar pra nada que vá ser carregado.

Comment: Sim, perdão. Estava testando o **printf** e o **println**, ai nesse exemplo acabei misturando os dois kkkk. Mas mesmo corrigindo, apresentava o mesmo erro.

Comment: Ah, me enganei novamente... não existe mesmo, foi um site "popular" que estava com informação errada. Bom, para usar `printf` só use se for precisar de: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax / se não use `System.out.println("Hello World!");`

Comment: Certo, obrigado. Mas você poderia me dizer para que serve esse **classpath**. ?

Comment: Pra buscar classes externas, o atalho é `-cp`. Vou trancar os comentários porque essa sessão não é para tirar duvidas extras, é para especificar ou solicitar detalhes especificos da pergunta. Para participar do site recomendo que entenda o ambiente primeiro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour / https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help - .  Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).